# How do I clean a data with hash and array mixed?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a hash data like this:

```
{
  "current_condition" => [
    {
      "cloudcover"       => "100",
      "humidity"         => "100",
      "observation_time" => "05:44 AM",
      "precipMM"         => "0.0",
      "pressure"         => "1015",
      "temp_C"           => "14",
      "temp_F"           => "57",
      "visibility"       => "13",
      "weatherCode"      => "122",
      "weatherDesc"      => [
        {
          "value" => "Overcast"
        }
      ],
      "weatherIconUrl" => [
        {
          "value" => "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png"
        }
      ],
      "winddir16Point" => "NNW",
      "winddirDegree"  => "340",
      "windspeedKmph"  => "15",
      "windspeedMiles" => "9"
    }
  ], 
  "request" => [
    {
      "query" => "94127",
      "type"  => "Zipcode"
    }
  ],
  "weather" => [
    {
      "date"        => "2012-09-09",
      "precipMM"    => "0.0",
      "tempMaxC"    => "21",
      "tempMaxF"    => "69",
      "tempMinC"    => "12",
      "tempMinF"    => "53",
      "weatherCode" => "113",
      "weatherDesc" => [
        {
          "value" => "Sunny"
        }
      ],
      "weatherIconUrl" => [
        {
          "value" => "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"
        }
      ],
      "winddir16Point" => "W",
      "winddirDegree"  => "279",
      "winddirection"  => "W",
      "windspeedKmph"  => "23",
      "windspeedMiles" => "14"
    },
    {
      "date"        => "2012-09-10",
      "precipMM"    => "0.1",
      "tempMaxC"    => "20",
      "tempMaxF"    => "68",
      "tempMinC"    => "12",
      "tempMinF"    => "53",
      "weatherCode" => "119",
      "weatherDesc" => [
        {
          "value" => "Cloudy"
        }
      ],
      "weatherIconUrl" => [
        {
          "value" => "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0003_white_cloud.png"
        }
      ],
      "winddir16Point" => "WSW",
      "winddirDegree"  => "252",
      "winddirection"  => "WSW",
      "windspeedKmph"  => "17",
      "windspeedMiles" => "11"
    }
  ]
}
```

Some of the hash values are just strings, some of them are arrays with only one element like this:

```
"weatherDesc"=>[{"value"=>"Cloudy"}]
```

I want to make all the elements like this in the hash to be like:

```
"weatherDesc"=>{"value"=>"Cloudy"}
```

Is there an easy Ruby method, or a single loop that can do this? Or do I need to loop through each key-val pair to flatten this?

--update -9-11-2012

Thanks for those who discussed and helped me out. Here's an update, I just found that there's actually one hash value has 2 objects in the array, I modified the @iioiooioo 's code in this line

```
hash[k] = v.first if v.is_a?( Array ) && v.count == 1
```

--more update on this, that above doesn't work correctly since there are arrays in the array who doesn't get cleaned since the array with 2 elements is not processed, which would end the recursion on it. I end up doing this, which is not pretty but...

```
def arr_to_hash(a)
  hash = {}
  for i in 0..a.length-1
      hash[i.to_s] = a[i]
  end
  hash
end

def clean_it( hash )
  hash.each do |k,v|
  hash[k] = arr_to_hash v if v.is_a?( Array ) && v.count > 1
  hash[k] = v.first if v.is_a?( Array ) && v.count == 1
  clean_it( hash[k] ) if hash[k].is_a?( Hash )
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, if you would reformat your hash to be more readable, that would help.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I guess it's not very very simple. Maybe this loop should be something like DFS to flatten every array in the hash, since it's nested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe a simple loop will suffice, I think you need to use recursion, like so:

```
a = {"current_condition"=> [{"cloudcover"=>"100", "humidity"=>"100", "observation_time"=>"05:44 AM", "precipMM"=>"0.0", "pressure"=>"1015", "temp_C"=>"14", "temp_F"=>"57", "visibility"=>"13", "weatherCode"=>"122", "weatherDesc"=>[{"value"=>"Overcast"}], "weatherIconUrl"=>[{"value"=>"http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png"}], "winddir16Point"=>"NNW", "winddirDegree"=>"340", "windspeedKmph"=>"15", "windspeedMiles"=>"9"}], "request"=>[{"query"=>"94127", "type"=>"Zipcode"}], "weather"=>[{"date"=>"2012-09-09", "precipMM"=>"0.0", "tempMaxC"=>"21", "tempMaxF"=>"69", "tempMinC"=>"12", "tempMinF"=>"53", "weatherCode"=>"113", "weatherDesc"=>[{"value"=>"Sunny"}], "weatherIconUrl"=>[{"value"=>"http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png"}], "winddir16Point"=>"W", "winddirDegree"=>"279", "winddirection"=>"W", "windspeedKmph"=>"23", "windspeedMiles"=>"14"}, {"date"=>"2012-09-10", "precipMM"=>"0.1", "tempMaxC"=>"20", "tempMaxF"=>"68", "tempMinC"=>"12", "tempMinF"=>"53", "weatherCode"=>"119", "weatherDesc"=>[{"value"=>"Cloudy"}], "weatherIconUrl"=>[{"value"=>"http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0003_white_cloud.png"}], "winddir16Point"=>"WSW", "winddirDegree"=>"252", "winddirection"=>"WSW", "windspeedKmph"=>"17", "windspeedMiles"=>"11"}]}


def clean_it( hash )

 hash.each do |k,v|
  hash[k] = v.first if v.is_a?( Array )
  clean_it( hash[k] ) if hash[k].is_a?( Hash )
 end

end

clean_it( a )

p a
```

Outputs:

```
{"current_condition"=>{"cloudcover"=>"100", "humidity"=>"100", "observation_time"=>"05:44 AM", "precipMM"=>"0.0", "pressure"=>"1015", "temp_C"=>"14", "temp_F"=>"57", "visibility"=>"13", "weatherCode"=
>"122", "weatherDesc"=>{"value"=>"Overcast"}, "weatherIconUrl"=>{"value"=>"http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud.png"}, "winddir16Point"=>"NNW", "wind
dirDegree"=>"340", "windspeedKmph"=>"15", "windspeedMiles"=>"9"}, "request"=>{"query"=>"94127", "type"=>"Zipcode"}, "weather"=>{"date"=>"2012-09-09", "precipMM"=>"0.0", "tempMaxC"=>"21", "tempMaxF"=>"
69", "tempMinC"=>"12", "tempMinF"=>"53", "weatherCode"=>"113", "weatherDesc"=>{"value"=>"Sunny"}, "weatherIconUrl"=>{"value"=>"http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0001_s
unny.png"}, "winddir16Point"=>"W", "winddirDegree"=>"279", "winddirection"=>"W", "windspeedKmph"=>"23", "windspeedMiles"=>"14"}}
```

Comment: Oh yes, recursion!! I should have thought of that. And your code is very clear and concise. Thank you!!

Comment: Oops, my bad, there's actually one value of the hash is an array of two objects. I guess modifying this line would work. 

`hash[k] = v.first if v.is_a?( Array ) && v.count == 1`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @iioiooioo, you should definitely use recursion. I think this should do what you want:

```
def collapse(obj)
  return obj unless obj.respond_to? :each
  if obj.is_a? Array
    ary = obj.map{ |elem| collapse elem }
    ary.first if ary.length == 1
  elsif obj.is_a? Hash
    obj.each { |key, val| obj[key] = collapse val }
    obj
  end
end
```